# How to select a value from Dropdown without using SELECT statement

Tags: java, selenium, select

In my automation suite I want to select a value from dropdown without using SELECT statement. Can someone please help me out with this.

Example:
I want to select a country name(India) from dropdown and I should not be using SELECT here.

Automation suite(Selenium with java)

Code:

```
<div id="pie_register_reg_form"> 
    <form id="pie_regiser_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/registration/">
    <ul id="pie_register">
    <div class="fieldset">
    <label for="dropdown_7">Country</label>
        <select id="dropdown_7" class="piereg_validate[required]" name="dropdown_7">
        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
        <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
        …
        <option value="India">India</option>
        …
        <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
        <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
```

I can select India from dropdown using the below code.

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("path of the dropdown")));
select.selectByVisibleText("India");
```

But I don't want to use `Select` here. Is there any other way to select India from dropdown.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Attach html code and be more descriptive

Comment: <div id="pie_register_reg_form">
 <form id="pie_regiser_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/registration/">
 <ul id="pie_register">
 <div class="fieldset">
<label for="dropdown_7">Country</label>
 <select id="dropdown_7" class="piereg_validate[required]" name="dropdown_7">
<option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Albania">Albania</option>
<option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
…
<option value="India">India</option>
…
<option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
<option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
</div>
</li>

Comment: I can select India from dropdown using the below code.

Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("path of the dropdown")));
  select.selectByVisibleText("India");

But I dont want to use "Select" here. Is there any other way to select India from dropdown.

Comment: @user3008227 Any particular reason to avoid `Select` class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following alternative for selection of values from drop down:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("path of the dropdown")).sendKeys("India");
```

Try this one. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//path of dropdown"));

List<WebElement> allOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@id='xxxxx']//option")); //get all the options from the dropdown

for(WebElement option : allOptions) {   
if (option.getText().equals("India")) 
{

option.click();

}

}
```

This code can be used